# 2048 game in Python

Tags: python, list, 2048

As a beginner I started to code a 2048 game. I made the matrix and filled it with 0's. Then I wanted to write a function which loops trough the whole matrix and find all the 0 values. Then save the coordinates of the 0 values and later replace them with 2 or 4 values. I made a random variable to choose beetween 2 or 4. The problem is, that i don't really know how to push the x and y coordinates of the 0 values to and array and then read them.

```
table = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0]]


options = []



def saveOptions(i, j):
     options.append([{i , j}])
     return options




def optionsReaderandAdder(options):
    if len(options) > 0:
        spot = random.random(options)
        r = random.randint(0, 1)
        if r > 0.5:
            table  <-------- THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE 0 TO 2 OR 4.










def optionsFinder():
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            if table[i][j] == 0:
                saveOptions(i, j)

    optionsReaderandAdder(options)


addNumber()

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row])
                 for row in table]))
```

Comment: `{i , j}` is an unordered `set`. You probably want a `tuple`, `(i , j)`. Unless 2048 is symmetrical, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the rows and columns of the table:

```
for row in table:
    for element in row:
        if element == 0:
             # now what?
```

We don't know what the coordinate is.

Python has a useful function named [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). We can iterate the same way as previously, but we also get the index, or position into the array.

```
zeroes = []

for i, row in enumerate(table):
    for j, element in enumerate(row):
        if element == 0:
             zeroes.append((i, j))
```

We can then set the values, for example all to `2`:

```
for i, j in zeroes:
    table[i][j] = 2
```

Your random code looks fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! Gonna look at it home